# I can't properly position an item of my navbar

Tags: html, css, symfony, navbar

I work under Symfony 3 and in my file base.html.twig I have among others a navbar which contains links on my pages.

And on the far right, it also contains a logout link that must be preceded by the username of the logged-in user.

Only, I can not properly position the username of the user to be well aligned with the disconnect link. I tried in every way, but nothing to do ...

And here is the rendering of the navbar

[image: navbar]

This is my code:

**base.html.twig:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>{% block title %}Antivirus{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block stylesheets %}


    {% endblock %}
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/baner.css') }}">

    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body style="background-color:#f2f2f2;">

    <div class="hero-image">
        <div class="hero-text">
            <h1>Site</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{path('connexion_index')}}">Atelech</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor01"
            aria-controls="navbarColor01" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{path('connexion_index')}}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{{path('user_packages')}}">Packages</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{path('accueil')}}">Sécurité informatique</a>
                </li>
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') %}
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Gestion</a>

                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{path('paquets_index')}}">Packages</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{path('informations_index')}}">Informations</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{path('utilisateurs_index')}}">Utilisateurs</a>
                            <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Statistiques</a>
                        </div>
                   </li> 
                {% endif %}
                {% if is_granted('ROLE_USER') %}
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="{{path('fos_user_profile_show')}}">Mon compte</a>
                    </li>
                {% endif %}

            </ul>

            {% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">{{ app.user.username }} </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Déconnexion</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}

        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
    {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    {% block fos_user_content %}{% endblock %}
</body>

</html>
```

And I put in isolation here the part of the file which poses me problem:

```
{% if is_granted("IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED") %}
                <div class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> 
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor01">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">{{ app.user.username }} </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ path('fos_user_security_logout') }}">Déconnexion</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endif %}
```

Someone would know what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add This class for user li `pt-2 text-white pr-2`

```
<li class="nav-item pt-2 text-white pr-2">{{ app.user.username }} </li>
```

Comment: Oh great, I did not know we could position like that a <li>, thank you!